# createCollection Privileges Still works even after revoke

Tags: mongodb

I created a role, and assigned find and insert only. I dont want the user to create new collection on their own. 
So, i revoke CreateCollection, but still the user can create the collections.

```
1. Login to the app database.
2. Created a role with insert and find Privileges only.
3. Created a user and assigned the role to the user.

App database
1. Logged into app database
2. tried to create collection,
3. Collection created.
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#createCollection), create collection privilege applies to createCollection method. The documentation does not say that it prevents implicit collection creation as part of an insert.

So, I suggest you test whether your user is able to execute `createCollection` explicitly.

Another possibility is that create collection privilege is meant to permit collection creation but not insert, and having the insert privilege implicitly grants collection creation including for the explicit `createCollection` call.

Since MongoDB creates collections automatically as needed, what are you trying to accomplish by denying this privilege to a user that is allowed to insert data?

Comment: thanks for the info. the goal was to restrict developers from not creating new collections and inserting data into them. But, I will take your advise of explicit insert privilege is assigned to only to specified collection.